# Ethereum Code Fork on Github : How to incorporate the majority of Ethereum updates quickly and seamlessly

Tags: quorum

There are currently 6831 fork on go ethereum on github. Say I have made multiple code changes to go ethereum client for private ethereum purposes, How can I incorporate the majority of Ethereum updates quickly and seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

If you merge your code with main ethereum repo, is there any conflict code? If not, then just merge/rebase your code with latest version of main ethereum repo.

I think the best merge strategy is merge your change into the lastest source code of ethereum main repo.